# Is it forbidden to help idolaters become righteous Noahides?

Tags: avodah-zarah, christianity, repentance-teshuvah, noachide-laws, noahidism

I heard from a Rabbi who cited Rambam that it is forbidden to help idolaters do teshuvah.

Does that mean it is forbidden to persuade them that they follow fake religions and that Judaism is the only true religion so that they become righteous Noahides?

I have a few Christian friends, and I'd like to send them videos which disprove Christianity and prove Torah's validity.

Comment: Any recollection where in the Rambam this prohibiition was sourced?

Comment: He didn't mention where Rambam said it

Answer (score 2):

1. Christian is not necessarily equal to idolater.
2. Concerning people that are fully convinced in their ways and even preaching to others, the best way is to stick to that Rambam. However, for those who hesitate and are open to hearing other views, it is a Mitzvah to minimize the overall Chilul Hashem in the world. That what Abraham was and many Chabadnikes are practically busy with - converting the gentiles from being wrongdoers to being righteous.

Comment: Thank you:) "Christian is not necessarily equal to idolater" - could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Could you also specify where Rambam expresses his view on the subject, please?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [according to HaRav Asher Weiss shlita](https://en.tvunah.org/2015/05/27/bnei-noach/) there is "no prohibition" in encouraging non-Jews to observe the sheva mitzvos bnei-Noach and it is "certainly a meritorious act".

Answer (score 1):

The Rebbe of Lubavitch [used to say about influencing those around us](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPyNN3q2SKU) on proper level, [being example of moral and civility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWArf_Y9qys) in order to improve the world, that is, making to them (directly and indirectly) aware of the Sheva Mitzvot Bnei Noach. Per his words, i understant that this implies to interact in a pleasant manner with them, avoiding confront and combative behavior (toward their existing beliefs).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Book of Mishlei, I surprisingly stumbled upon an apparent answer to my question.

In [Mishlei 9:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16380#showrashi=true) we read:

> He who chastens a scorner takes disgrace for himself, and he who
>   reproves a wicked man, that is his blemish.

[Rashi](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16380#showrashi=true) comments:

> **and he who reproves a wicked man, that is his blemish:** It is a blemish to the one who reproves [him], for this one berates him and
>   does not heed him. This is a warning that it is forbidden to talk with
>   those who entice to worship idols, even to reprove them and to draw
>   them near.

King Solomon and Rashi basically say it's a waste of time and nerves to convince Christians and other idolaters to abandon idolatry. They will still cling to their stupidity and hate you for showing them how stupid they are (my experience confirms the proverb is true).

Comment: We should always help Jews first, then non-Jews. Try your luck with the Rambam. Maybe they will see how rational he is and want to convert to Judaism. Evidently, Rambam says that in the messianic time, everyone will convert to Judaism.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not forbidden. In fact, Maimonides said Moshe was tasked to convince the world to accept the 7 Noahide laws. Source: "Holy War in Judaism: The Fall and Rise of a Controversial Idea" by Reuven Firestone

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? It appears to answer the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you did not specify your sources

Comment: @DanWeisberg, the source is from "Holy War in Judaism: The Fall and Rise of a Controversial Idea" by Reuven Firestone

Comment: maybe you should cite it in your answer